# Eclipse Mars consistently fails resolving imports after saving, but cleaning projects alone solves

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, build

This started to happen to me and all my teammates at some point and we cannot figure out what is that triggered that and how to solve that.
We all have the same Java projects in our workspaces. In `Project` menu we all have `Build automatically` ticked.
Let's say that my workspace has no compilation errors. I make a trivial change to one of the Java classes, I save, Eclipse starts rebuilding and the result is that hundreds of classes - in more than one project - have now compilation errors. That is because for some reason a lot of `import` statements now show the error *The import [xxx] cannot be resolved*.
But those `import`s (and the whole workspace for that matter) were perfectly error-free before I saved my trivial, completely unrelated change, and they all go back to being perfectly error-free if at this point I just do `Project / Clean` which of course triggers a workspace rebuild.

The `.log` file in the workspace folder doesn't show anything; if it's empty before I save, it's still empty after my save caused those errors to appear.

This is way more annoying than it might sound, because building the whole workspace can take minutes, and since a mere `Project / Clean` makes all failing `import`s work again this cannot be due to something wrong in our code.

I know this is a long shot but considering how reproducible this issue is for us (100% of the times on 100% of the several computers involved) maybe someone else had the same problem and discovered the cause or a solution.

The version is *Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers*, Mars.1 Release (4.5.1), on Windows 8.

We use Gradle (2.6) by creating External Tool Configurations that point to `gradlew.bat` and with a string prompt. We run those manually to configure the projects after importing them into Eclipse (by entering `eclipse` in the string prompt) and to build the JARs for the deployment (by entering `build` in the string prompt), however I don't think Gradle is involved in the problematic build by Eclipse.

**ADDED:** I'm no longer sure it's accurate to say that this problem is 100% reproducible, because the following happens:

- Initial state: no errors present (which can only be because I cleaned all projects) and no unsaved changes.
- I make a change to a class in the editor, I save and that generates the errors.
- I undo that change, save and clean; so I'm back to exactly the initial state.
- I redo that change (identical), I save and this time I don't get the errors.

**ADDED:** Using `javap` to inspect the generated `.class` files, I notice the 2 following things:

1) Minor and major versions are always the same no matter the `.class` file got built with the errors or without (minor version: 0; major version: 51). Of course when the `.class` file is built with the errors it contains the error messages while when it's built without the errors it doesn't contain the error messages.

2) Comparing the outputs of `javap` for both `.class` files, I see that in the "Constant pool" section the lines are identical (showing names of class members and objects, f.ex. `Ljava/lang/String;`) up until a line about a class `my.package.MyClassImpl` where the problematic `.class` file has

`#32 = Utf8               LMyClassImpl;`

and the correct `.class` file has the same but fully qualified:

`#32 = Utf8               Lmy.package.MyClassImpl;`

I'm sure this has to do with the problem.

**ADDED:** **The problem disappears** if I tick the “*Rebuild class files modified by others*” checkbox in Eclipse preferences under `Java / Compiler / Building / Output folder`. At least all the cases where a certain change was showing the problem don't show it any longer.
This is just a workaround and I'm keeping investigating the root cause, however this hints strongly towards [Eclipse’s internal Java compiler](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-java-builder.htm) playing a major role in this problem.

**ADDED:** Below is the content of the `.classpath` and `.project` files of two of the projects. The first project is one that shows those compilation errors. The second project is one that never does. I had to replace many lines with `....` in one file because of the 30.000 chars limit and I can't seem to be able to find how to attach files; if that is allowed and someone points me to how to do that I will attach them without cuts and remove their content from the question.

Note the interesting difference that the first `.classpath` has an entry `excluding="**/*.class"` and the second doesn't. However when I modify the Java Build Path of all the projects that have that *through Eclipse (Project Properties / Java Build Path / Source)* removing their `excluded:**/*.class` the resulting `.classpath` files don't have that entry but the compilation errors appear anyway (also after restarting Eclipse). And if I do the opposite (i.e. add `excluded:**/*.class` to all projects that don't have it) then the `.classpath` files of all the projects get that entry but the compilation errors still show up. I would have bet that this would solve the problem but it doesn't.

**`MyProjectThatGetsErrors`**: `.project` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>MyProjectThatGetsErrors</name>
    <comment/>
    <projects/>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments/>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <linkedResources/>
</projectDescription>
```

**`MyProjectThatGetsErrors`**: `.classpath` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry excluding="**/*.class" kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="/MyUtilsProject1"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="/MyUtilsProject2"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-io/8.1.15.v20140411/8849cf59187275366cd05f37b2fb71319291370b/jetty-io-8.1.15.v20140411.jar" sourcepath="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-io/8.1.15.v20140411/49fd78caf4ca0c7cdbc532fc48ff46183bb8fb62/jetty-io-8.1.15.v20140411-sources.jar"/>
....
....
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/EclipseMars/git/MyProjectThatGetsErrors/lib/tapestry5-highcharts-1.2.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

**`MyUtilsProject1`**: `.project` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>MyUtilsProject1</name>
    <comment/>
    <projects/>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments/>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <linkedResources/>
</projectDescription>
```

**`MyUtilsProject1`**: `.classpath` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/dc6a73fdbd1fa3f0944e8497c6c872fa21dca37e/commons-digester-1.8.jar" sourcepath="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/6c296de7dc352e0af9a40f92f5af995314d41fc9/commons-digester-1.8-sources.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/90a3822c38ec8c996e84c16a3477ef632cbc87a3/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar" sourcepath="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/d2a489573c0ed2c4942b3660decad5d65087b406/commons-lang3-3.3.2-sources.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/32cadde23955d7681b0d94a2715846d20b425235/commons-configuration-1.6.jar" sourcepath="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/2d24067548bf9022d03cfd6ca302e1f6c5d4936/commons-configuration-1.6-sources.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.2/a10c06183fe21f3bb3dda3b5946b93db6e2ad5cc/commons-fileupload-1.2.jar" sourcepath="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.2/c7859b375ae5bc1b4a4f2b91ce6d1d387e676e61/commons-fileupload-1.2-sources.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-core/1.8.0/175dc721f87e4bc5cc0573f990e28c3cf9117508/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.velocity/velocity/1.7/2ceb567b8f3f21118ecdec129fe1271dbc09aa7a/velocity-1.7.jar" sourcepath="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.velocity/velocity/1.7/eb11eb70171ed64842b2e5216d5904e21ed162ac/velocity-1.7-sources.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/761ea405b9b37ced573d2df0d1e3a4e0f9edc668/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar" sourcepath="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/fa095ef874374e5b2a11f8b06c26a5d68c7cb3a4/commons-collections-3.2.1-sources.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/5675fd96b29656504b86029551973d60fb41339b/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar" sourcepath="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/b68c4fc66026e8c08df7fb57c7dc1e94a6ed8cbb/commons-beanutils-1.7.0-sources.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/16313e02a793435009f1e458fa4af5d879f6fb11/commons-lang-2.4.jar" sourcepath="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/2b8c4b3035e45520ef42033e823c7d33e4b4402c/commons-lang-2.4-sources.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/5043bfebc3db072ed80fbd362e7caf00e885d8ae/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar" sourcepath="C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/f3f156cbff0e0fb0d64bfce31a352cce4a33bc19/commons-logging-1.1.1-sources.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/EclipseMars/git/MyUtilsProject1/lib/MyCompany cayenne-client-3.0.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

**ADDED:** When I switch to a different Git branch or pull changes into my workspace, which of course causes those compilation errors to appear, ***sometimes*** Eclipse shows an error dialog about a `NullPointerException` in the Java Builder, and in that case it does write it in the log (see stacktrace below). However 99% of the times when those errors show up there is no such null pointer.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 75 2015-11-10 13:51:31.544
!MESSAGE Errors occurred during the build.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 75 2015-11-10 13:51:31.544
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'MyProject'.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ReferenceBinding$2.compare(ReferenceBinding.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ReferenceBinding$2.compare(ReferenceBinding.java:1)
    at java.util.TimSort.binarySort(TimSort.java:265)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:208)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ReferenceBinding.sortFields(ReferenceBinding.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.fields(BinaryTypeBinding.java:946)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding.fields(ParameterizedTypeBinding.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding.getField(ParameterizedTypeBinding.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.findField(Scope.java:1371)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.FieldDeclaration.resolve(FieldDeclaration.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.FieldBinding.constant(FieldBinding.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.FieldBinding.constant(FieldBinding.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.QualifiedNameReference.getOtherFieldBindings(QualifiedNameReference.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.QualifiedNameReference.resolveType(QualifiedNameReference.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ReturnStatement.resolve(ReturnStatement.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(MethodDeclaration.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolve(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1188)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1301)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ProcessTaskManager.run(ProcessTaskManager.java:141)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Are you using a second, external build tool, e.g. Maven?

Comment: @CedricReichenbach Good point, I just added these info at the bottom of the question, I should have done that since the beginning. I'm not sure Maven is involved in the problematic build triggered by Eclipse but it could certainly be and it's something that for sure I should have mentioned anyway, thanks.

Comment: Ok, I seem to have a very similar problem. What I've observed: Errors only appear in the files I've just saved, and all of my failing dependencies point to classes inside my own projects (in the build scope). Thus, Eclipse probably only automatically compiles one file at a time and for some reasons thinks the others are already built, but those class files are either non-existent or incompatible. Have you compared Java versions used in Gradle and Eclipse?

Comment: @CedricReichenbach I have the feeling that your hypothesis is along the right track, although I'm not sure how Gradle could be involved; but Maven sounds more likely to be. I don't know how to check the Java version used by either one but when I have time I will try to figure that out and post the result.

Comment: Just do a build and search for "java" or "version" in the console output - it's usually printed somewhere.

Comment: Nope, but I will try to add some code in `build.gradle` to make it print the Java version. I'm still unable to see how Gradle can be involved at all but this issue is so messed up that I abandoned any hope of getting to the bottom of it through my scarce knowledge of the subject and through reasoning and I will try everything. Re _"Errors only appear in the files I've just saved"_, in my case it's different, the unresolved `import`s appear in hundreds of different classes, but all inside my own projects as well; only in 3 specific projects out of the 7 that we have in our workspaces though.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach I just appended some further Gradle-related info to the question.

Comment: I'm confused; are you saying you use both Gradle and Maven in this project?

Comment: Also, can you post the contents of your .project and .classpath files for one of the problematic projects?

Comment: @E-Riz We use Gradle to configure the Java projects after we imported them into Eclipse, and to build the JARs for the deployment. At the stage where the `.class` files with the errors get created, in my understanding Gradle has not been involved. We run Gradle manually through External Tool Configurations that point to `gradlew.bat`, to do one of the 2 above mentioned things.
About Maven, I just found those 3 Features listed under Installation Details in Eclipse. They are probably bundled into Eclipse and AFAIK we don't use them. My _feeling_ is that neither Gradle nor Maven are involved.

Comment: @E-Riz I appended to the question the `.project` and `.classpath` files of two of the involved projects.

Comment: Did you try disabling and enabling the eclipse Builders incrementally in order to analyze the source of this issue?  This is done by Project-->properties-->Builders. Note that Builders have a strict order which affects the build results.

Comment: @Leet-Falcon I would like to try that but I'm not sure what outcome to expect or how to process it, because under Project / Properties / Builders all the 7 projects have only one entry, "_Java Builder_", whose checkbox is ticked, and when I untick it I get a confirmation dialog saying "_This is an advanced operation. Disabling a project builder can have many side-effects. Continue?_". If I disable the only one builder a project has then at that point I'd have no idea what will be building my `.class` files - if anything will at all. If someone can help me understand this I'd like to try.

Comment: @SantiBailors - You should have another builder called "Maven Project Builder"...

Comment: @Leet-Falcon I don't have that. Only "_Java Builder_", in all projects.

Comment: @SantiBailors, OK. It seems, for once, Maven is not to blame here... Try to create a custom builder and call "gradlew.bat" or any other tool which may affect your Java build (Builders-->New-->Program) before the Java builder. Press "Up" to place it first in Builders line.

Comment: @E-Riz et al. JFI I just appended to the question some info about a `NullPointerException` that _very occasionally_ the Java Builder throws in conjunction with a workspace rebuild that triggers those compilation errors.

Comment: It could be some obscure Eclipse bug. Did someone update your (shared) Save Actions setting for Eclipse at some point? 

Check whether "Remove Unused Imports" is set under `Preferences\Java\Editor\Save Actions\Additional Actions\Unneccessary Code`. I've experienced a similar behavior on older Eclipse versions when this option is combined with "Format source code\Format all lines"

Comment: @YiannisDermitzakis Well that's intriguing; we did update our shared Save Actions settings recently (we share them through Oomph). In the preferences page you mention there is no "Remove Unused Imports" but there is "Organize Imports" and "Format source code", although neither is ticked. But just to be sure I'm totally going to disable the Save Actions altogether and see if that makes a difference; I'll post feedback about that afterwards. I get the feeling that E-Riz answer is spot on and I'm looking into that but testing your hypothesis is very easy so I'll do that too.

Comment: @YiannisDermitzakis Disabling the Save Actions didn't help. Actually the problem also occurs when I replace a file with a different revision, not only when I save. But it was worth a shot.

Comment: BTW is now confirmed on several PCs (all the ones that tried) that ticking the “_Rebuild class files modified by others_” checkbox in Eclipse preferences under `Java / Compiler / Building / Output folder` makes the problem **go away completely**. Of course it's just a workaround but it makes sense, is not a hack and might help greatly a possible investigation of the exact root of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the root of your problem is due to the fact that you're trying to use Gradle to tell Eclipse how Eclipse should configure your projects. There is a bit of conflict between Gradle (or Maven) and Eclipse; unfortunately, the Gradle (and Maven) teams have pushed the idea that the build tool is good for generating IDE configurations, when in fact they're not very good at it. The IDE (and developer using it) should be responsible for creating and managing its project configuration files.

Eclipse has Gradle tooling that you can install and knows exactly how to configure and maintain your Eclipse projects correctly based on the build.gradle files in them. It's called [Buildship](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/blob/master/README.md). I strongly recommend you [install Buildship](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/buildship-gradle-integration) and use it to import the projects into your Eclipse workspace. It will properly set up a Classpath Container that stays in sync with the dependencies listed in your build files, as well as properly coordinate the work that Eclipse's compiler needs to do and the work that Gradle itself needs to do so they don't conflict with each other.

It also provides a nice Gradle tasks view that you can use to easily invoke Gradle tasks from within Eclipse (replacing your homemade External Tools configuration).

Comment: Thanks for the edit to my question, it's clearer now, and for the info about possible conflicts between Eclipse and project configuration done through Gradle; I think I can relate to the idea of Gradle being more a build tool (a great one) than a project configuration tool. I will look into Buildship and ask my teammates to do the same and possibly decide to use it. If you (or anyone) can provide some link discussing the idea that Gradle is not very suited for configuration tasks - in general or compared to Buildship - that would be very useful.